# How to get distinct Items by one field in MongoDB using @Query annotation with pagination enabled

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-webflux, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-mongodb-reactive

I'm trying to get the list of distinct items by a specific field (userId). Currently I'm using this kind of approach to get records from MongoDB using `ReactiveCrudRepository`. Additionally, I want this result to be further filtered and get only the distinct items.

How to do this?

```
@Query(value = "{$and :[{'submitTime':{$ne:null}}, {'gameId': :#{#gameId}} ]}", sort = "{'score': -1, 'timeTaken': 1, 'submitTime': 1}")
Flux<Play> getWinners(@Param("gameId") String gameId, Pageable pageable);
```

My `Play` object is like this:

```
@Document(value = "play")
@Builder
public class Play {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String gameId;
    private int score;
    private String userId;
    private LocalDateTime submitTime;
    private long timeTaken;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At the moment @Query annotation doesn't provide a possibility to execute the distinct command.
As a workaround you can

- implement a custom method with find, sort and distinct actions
- use [.distinct()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#distinct-java.util.function.Function-) operator after calling your repo method getWinners() to distinct items by key selector, but in this case this operation will not be performed in MongoDB